# Proving lower bound for $\frac{\|\mathbf{\phi}({a})-\mathbf{\phi}({b})\|} {\|{a}-{b}\|}$

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, continuity

Suppose $\phi: \mathbb R^n\to \mathbb R^n$ is $C^1$ and that $a, b\in \mathbb R^n$ are distinct. Let $D\phi(x)$ denote the Jacobian of $\phi$ at $x$.

While reading some proof, I came across the following statement without much justification.

$\| D\mathbf{\phi}({b})\Big( \frac{a-b}{\|{a}-{b}\|}\Big )\|- \Big [\frac{1}{\|{a}-{b}\|}(\| \mathbf{\phi}({a})-\mathbf{\phi}({b})-D\mathbf{\phi}({b})({a}-{b})\|) \Big]\leq \frac{\|\mathbf{\phi}({a})-\mathbf{\phi}({b})\|}
{\|{a}-{b}\|}$.

I can't figure out why this is true. I have tried the Mean Value Theorem but without success. I'd appreciate it if someone could explain this inequality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put $X=D\mathbf{\phi}({b})\Big( \frac{a-b}{\|{a}-{b}\|}\Big )$ and $Y=\frac{1}{\|{a}-{b}\|}( \mathbf{\phi}({a})-\mathbf{\phi}({b})-D\mathbf{\phi}({b})({a}-{b}) $.

Then:

$||X||-||Y|| \le ||X+Y||=\frac{||\mathbf{\phi}({a})-\mathbf{\phi}({b})||}{||a-b||}$

Comment: How do the $D\phi(b)$ cancel?

Comment: You may want $\|X+Y\|$, but thank you.

Comment: OOps ! Yes $\|X+Y\|$